Put my product categories and variants from my website to Amazon using SP API
I have a customer who got a website selling their products. Now they ask me to put product taxonomy and variants/options from the website to Amazon store. I've spent few weeks on reading SP API documentary but I just got blur vision about that and could not figure out which endpoints would work in my case. Is there any tips or articles somewhere to show it clearer, or recommend me the SP API endpoints could do those stuff?

Creating products on Amazon's catalog is one of the biggest challenge in using Amazon SP-APIs. For products with variations (e.g. clothing) is possibly even more difficult. A lot of informations are required and you must provide it carefully since, as soon as a product is ingested into Amazon's catalog, it may impossible for you to change them.
It might be easier if you just need to link your offers to existing products in Amazon's catalog.
In any case, if you already checked the "Building Listings Management Workflows Guide" and the "Manage product listings with the Selling Partner API" and you didn't succeed in reaching your goal, I can suggest you two different solutions:

carefully read my "How to list items on Amazon using SP-APIs" series on Medium. Here you can find: Part 1, Part 2 and Part 3. A couple of parts are still missing since I'm working on them right now. You will also find a link for my Whatsapp community for Amazon SP-API developers.
you can think about using a third-party solution provider to do that. One of this is MarketRock - disclaimer: I'm the CTO of MarketRock - and it provides a full set of API for doing that (i.e. catalog distribution) on different marketplaces. In any case, no solution will take for you the burden of gathering the required informations to list the product on the marketplace.

